# How do you solve the cauchy integral equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $$\frac{1}{2πi} ∮\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+ 1}dz = \sin t$$

if $t > 0$ and $C$ is the circle $|z|=3$.

Comment: Hint: Partial fractions

Comment: can that be simplified to $\dfrac{e^{(x+iy)t}}{(z+i)(z-i)}$

Comment: what does that integrate to?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You have two poles inside the contour, namely $z=i$ and $z=-i$. Calculate the residue at each pole and add them. Or just use the Cauchy integral formula

$$ \frac{1}{2πi} ∮\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+ 1}dz = \frac{1}{2πi}\left(\frac{-i}{2}\right) ∮\frac{e^{zt}}{z-i}dz - \frac{1}{2πi} \left(\frac{-i}{2}\right)∮\frac{e^{zt}}{z+i}dz = \dots $$

Comment: Do this; it's gonna work.

Comment: what's the final solution

Comment: @mad: first tell us the residues.

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy's Residue Theorem says the following:

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function everywhere on a circle and its interior, except maybe at the points $z_1,\dots,z_N$ where $f$ has poles of order $n_1,\dots,n_N$ (meaning $f^{-1}$ has a zero of order $n_N$). Then:

$$\frac{1}{2πi} ∮f(z) dz = \sum_{k=1}^{N} {\textrm res}_k f $$

where:

$${\textrm res}_i f = \lim_{z\rightarrow z_k}\frac{1}{(n_k-1)!}(\frac{d}{dz})^{n_k-1}(z-z_k)^{n_k}f(z)$$.

Here, $f = \dfrac{e^{zt}}{z^2+ 1}$. Compute the rest and you will see.