# Computing Residues

Tags: complex-analysis

How might one go about computing the residue of $\frac {z^2 + 3z - 1}{z+2}$?  I understand it has a pole at -2 and that we should then expand the numerator in powers of 2, but the book seems to do it by inspection.  How does it look when done methodically?

EDIT:  I should clarify - I understand I can just plug -2 into the numerator but I do not know why.

Comment: Did you write your function correctly? Why did you use some parentheses?

Comment: It seemed like a good idea at the time. Edited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points/346995#346995) is how check the order of the pole and notice that for the case of a simple pole it equals the residue. Now, $z=-2$ is a simple pole then the residue is the coeffiecient of $a_{-1}$ and it is given by

$$ \lim_{z\to -2}(z+2)\frac {(z^2 + 3z - 1)}{(z+2)}=\dots\,. $$

Other related problems [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367940/difficulties-performing-laurent-series-expansions-to-determine-residues/367956#367956), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322070/how-do-you-solve-the-cauchy-integral-equation).

Comment: I see, so it works because in this case the pole is simple.  Is the $(z+2)$ out front because of the definition of the residue or?

Comment: @user73041: Yes, this is the formula (see the link) for computing it in the case of a simple pole.

Comment: You can write $\dfrac{z^2+3z-1}{z+2}=az+b+\dfrac{c}{z+2}$, and $c$ is the so-called residue. Multiply both sides by $(z+2)$... But yes, the formula used above works for every simple pole!

Comment: Thank you both. Is it perhaps helpful to think as polynomials as terms in an expansion in general when dealing with simple poles then?

Comment: Another appoach to find residues is by deriving the Laurent series, but some times it requires a lot of work.