# Residue/Laurent series of $\frac{z}{1+\sin(z)}$ at $z=-\pi/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

For some reason, I just can't quite figure out how to easily calculate the Laurent series for the following function:

$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{1+\sin(z)},\quad z_0=-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

I don't really need the whole series, just the residue.  The function has a zero of order 2 at $z=-\pi/2$, which would lead to the nasty calculation:

$$
\text{Res}[f,z_0]=\lim_{z\rightarrow-\pi/2}\frac{d}{dz}(z+\pi/2)^2f(z)
$$  The derivative is nasty and we'd have to apply L'H$\hat{\text{o}}$pital's rule 4 times to get the denominator to not vanish (more nastiness).

So Laurent series it is!  But for some reason my worn out qual-studying brain can't figure out how to do it.  A hint would be lovely!

Comment: You could expand the numerator and the denominator in Taylor series about $z= - \frac{\pi}{2}$ and then use polynomial long division.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372914/computing-residues/372919#372919).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal That problem doesn't seem to help, the pole there is simple and the limit is easy to calculate.

Comment: @RandomVariable I thought of that, got scared, and ran away.  If that's the way to go I'll get to it!

Comment: Do you want the entire Laurent series (urgh), or only its principal part?

Comment: @DanielFischer I only need the residue, really.

Comment: @icurays1: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367940/difficulties-performing-laurent-series-expansions-to-determine-residues/367956#367956). Note that, the pole you have is of order 2.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes, I know.  As I said in my question, the residue is impractical to compute with that method.

Comment: @icurays1: The last link gives you the technique how to calculate. I hope you see it.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Ah, okay - I see it now (DonAntonio's answer).  Thanks.

Comment: @ icurays1 : You wrote:"we'd have to apply L'Ho^pital's rule 4 times to get the denominator to not vanish (more nastiness)". Is  L'Ho^pital's rule applicable to complex-valued functions?

Comment: @user64494 Yes, it is. Refer to any complex analysis book, e.g. Ahlfors

Comment: @ icurays1 : Can you give an exact reference indicating Chap., Par., etc? I don't find the L'hospital rule in my L. Ahlfors, Complex Analysis.

Comment: @user64494 I guess Ahlfors doesn't have it.  Mathews and Howell, page 202, or just look at Taylor series (top and bottom functions need to be analytic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $z = (-\pi/2) + w$. Then $\sin z = \sin (w-\pi/2) = -\cos w$.

Now, you can easily get the beginning of the Taylor expansion of $1 + \sin z$ around $-\pi/2$:

$$1 + \sin z = 1 - \bigl( 1 - \frac{w^2}{2} + \frac{w^4}{4!} - O(w^6)\bigr) = \frac{w^2}{2}\bigl(1 - \frac{w^2}{12} + O(w^4)\bigr)$$

and therefore

$$\begin{align}
\frac{z}{1+\sin z} &= \frac{w-\pi/2}{\frac{w^2}{2}\bigl(1 - \frac{w^2}{12} + O(w^4)\bigr)}\\
&= \frac{2w-\pi}{w^2}\bigl(1 + \frac{w^2}{12} + O(w^4)\bigr)\\
&= -\frac{\pi}{w^2} + \frac{2}{w} - \frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{w}{6} + O(w^2).
\end{align}$$

Now replace $w$ with $z - (-\pi/2)$.

Comment: Are you using a geometric series expansion to get from the first to the second line?

Comment: Yup. For small $\lvert w\rvert$, that's legitimate.

Comment: Excellent, I like this method.  Thanks!

Comment: There is a difference in the first term between our answers.

Comment: Ah, bloody signs. Thanks for the heads-up, @user64494

Comment: @icurays1 As you can see, one must be careful with the signs. I made a mistake there and wrote $z = w+\pi/2$ first, instead of $z = w-\pi/2$ for the numerator.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah, got it - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First write the function as a function of $x+\pi/2$.

$\sin(z)=\sin(z+\pi/2-\pi2)=\sin(z+\pi/2)\cos(-\pi/2)+\cos(z+\pi/2)\sin(-\pi/2)$

So, you function is

$$\frac{-\frac{\pi}{2}+(z+\frac{\pi}{2})}{1-\cos(z+\pi/2)}$$

Now, use long division to with the series of the numerator and denominator.

Take into account that 
$$\cos(x)=1-x^2/2+x^4/41+O(x^5).$$

Also take into account that for long division you need the the constant coefficient of the denominator to be non-zero. So, you would take $(z+\pi/2)^2$ out as a factor from the denominator before dividing, and put it back afterwards.