# Finding the order of a zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Studying for my complex analysis final, and I came across this question:

> Find the order of the zero of
>
> $$ f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{z-\pi/2} $$
>
> at $z=\pi/2$.

The order of the zero would just be one, right? This is because the polynomial in the denominator is of degree one.

Comment: What is the order of the zero of $\cos$ at $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: I don't think it's that easy. Note that $\cos \frac{\pi}{2} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ at the point $z=\pi/2$

> $$ \cos(x) = -(z+\pi/2) +O \left( (z-\pi/2  \right) ^{3}  ). $$

Check [other techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372914/computing-residues).

Answer (score 2):

$x=\pi/2$ is a simple zero both for $\cos x$ and $x-\pi/2$.

Hence $x=\pi/2$ **is not** a zero of your function, as you can see by computing:
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{x-\pi/2}=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{-\sin x}{1}=-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can think this way:

$f(z)$ has removable singularity in $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$, because:

$$\lim_{z \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos z}{z-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{-\sin z}{z}=-1$$

So the order of $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

$f(\pi/2)\neq 0$ then it's a zero of order $0$.