# Methods of evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2+1}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Methods of evaluating $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2+1}$$

---

Firstly i know that directly:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2+1}=\arctan x\Bigg|_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}2$$
Also we can use the contour integral:
$$\int_{\text{Line}}\frac{{\rm d}z}{z^2+1}+\underbrace{\int_{\text{Arc}}\frac{{\rm d}z}{z^2+1}}_{\text{zero}}=2\pi {\rm i}\;\substack{\large \text{Res}\\{z=i}}\;\frac{1}{z^2+1}=2\pi{\rm i}(1/(2i))=\pi$$
Since the line extends in both directions but we need only the positive side
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2+1}=\frac{\pi}2$$
Now I have two questions:

> - What methods can be used to evaluate the residue, can someone be detailed enough to explain in brief all useful? Note that I have too listed them below. Actually explain for the function $$\frac1{(z^2+1)^2}$$ at $z=i$
> - What other methods for evaluating the integral?

**Residue Methods I would use:** 
Laurent series, Some theorem which says residue for $\frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$ at $z_0$ is $\frac{\phi^{(m-1)}(z_0)}{(m-1)!}$, for pole of order 1 in a zero of the denominator of rational function we can diffrentiate the denominator once.

Comment: So you want to see the evaluation of $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z^2 + 1)^2}dz$$ via residue theorem?

Comment: @dustin I can do it, if you wish may i include it in the question? anyways i meant "different methods to evaluate".

Comment: @ADG you don't need to include it. I was just confused at what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let be
$$
I_n=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}
$$
We have
$$\begin{align}
I_n &= \underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\mathrm dx}_{I_n-1}-\int_0^{\infty}x\cdot \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}\mathrm dx\\
&=I_{n-1}-\underbrace{\left.\frac{x}{2(1-n)(x^2+1)^{n-1}}\right|_0^{\infty}}_{\to 0}+\frac{1}{2(1-n)}I_{n-1}
\end{align}
$$
and finally we obtain the recurrence relation

$$
I_n=\frac{2n-3}{2(n-1)}I_{n-1} \qquad (n>1)
$$
with
$$
I_1=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

For $n=2$, you have $I_2=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) to evaluate the integral. Using the substitution $t=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ casts the integral to

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} t^{1/2}\,(1-t)^{-1/2} dt = \beta( 3/2,1/2 )=\frac{\pi}{4}.  $$

**Note:**

> $$ \beta( 3/2,1/2 ) = \frac{\Gamma(3/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(2)} = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma(1/2)^2 = \frac{\pi}{2}. $$

Comment: do you know about other residue methods, are mine correct?

Comment: @ADG: You can use residue techniques. Just pay attention to the order of the poles. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372914/computing-residues).

Comment: @ADG: Note that you can use beta function to evaluate the first integral too.

Comment: yes it would be easy if you(actually me) remembered well about beta function, i haven't practised any questions of it yet, anyways thanks!!!

Comment: @ADG: You are welcome