# When $C$ is the positively oriented circle centered at 0 with a radius of 2, what is $\int_C \dfrac{1}{z^3+4z^2+3z}dz$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am reviewing for a complex analysis final and this was a question on the review sheet. No answers were provided so I attempted it on my own. Using Cauchy's Integral Formula, I have that
$$2\pi i \cdot f(z) = \int_C \dfrac{1}{z^3+4z^2+3z}dz = -\dfrac{\pi i}{3}.$$
If anyone wants to do this problem, the denominator factors into $z(z+1)(z+3).$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: As long as $\frac13 - \frac12 = - \frac16$, I agree with your result.

Comment: @Berci Sorry I wasn't entirely clear in asking my question. I basically just wanted someone else to double-check my work. I got the answer that I wrote up there. I was just hoping that someone else could verify that I was correct (which apparently I am).

Comment: @Daniel Fischer - And thank you.

Comment: What is the $\large C$ definition ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin $C$ denotes a circle that is positively oriented (counter-clockwise) with its center at 0 and it has a radius of 2. That was just the notation given for this particular problem. I've seen several other notations.

Comment: @BarkJr. 0 k. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_C \frac{1}{z(z+1)(z+3)} \, \mathrm{d}z = 2 \pi i \times Res\left(\frac{1}{z(z+1)(z+3)}; z=0, z=-1\right) = 2 \pi i \times (1/3 - 1/2) = - \frac{\pi i}{3}$. I agree with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

i) locate and classify the poles.

ii) use partial fraction.

iii) use Cauchy's formula.

See a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322070/how-do-you-solve-the-cauchy-integral-equation).